# Пробег через цикл и интерактивное отображение данных на вызывающей веб-странице

Tags: javascript, php, html5, циклы, pdo

Уважаемые коллеги, задаюсь вопросом: можно ли при помощи PHP/HTML5/JavaScript/CSS или других технологий реализовать "пробег" через PDO-recordset, *отображая результаты на вызывающей веб-странице в реальном времени*?

Есть результат SQL-запроса `SELECT product_id from Products` который возвращает 10 записей. Каждый `product_id` нужно подставить в URL `https://api.domain.com/?pid={product_id}` и все десять раз передать эту ссылку cURL'у.

То есть cURL должен десять раз в цикле выполнить API-запросы с разыми `product_id`. И - самое важное (искомое) - всё это должно интерактивно отображаться на веб-странице и желательно с каким-нибудь индикатором прогресса (gauge), в процентах или еще как-то визуализироваться. Или хотя бы в виде текста, например:

> Обработано значение {product_id}

Что-то подсказывает мне, что без JavaScript и, возможно, AJAX-запросов тут не обойтись, но пока я не могу представить себе такое решение. Может быть существуют какие-то законченные куски кода/фреймворки, которые реализовывают подобную функциональность. Дюжина моих запросов к англоязычным источникам, к сожалению, не увенчалась успехом.

В настоящее время мне приходится выполнять эту задачу через приложение на Delphi (Object Pascal), которое запускается на Windows и каждый запрос к API выполняется отдельным потоком. Но наверняка ведь существует изящное решение реализовать подобную функциональность непосредственно в браузере.

Comment: показ прогресса думаю только аяксом и возможен, что там сложного? прогресс-бар на css, первый запрос аякса - получить id продуктов, ставим их в очередь, последующие аякс-запросы один за одним на парсинг курлом, и после выполнения каждого к прогресс-бару 10%

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а может знаете какие-то готовые решения на эту тему?

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант на примере готового API (https://swapi.dev):

```js
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar')
let resultField = document.getElementById('resultField')

function loadList(count) {
  clear()
  let currentPercent = 100 / count
  console.log('currentPercent' + currentPercent)
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    let url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/' + i + '/?format=json'
    let result = request(url, 'GET')
    result.then(data => processResult(data, currentPercent))
  }
}

function processResult(data, currentPercent) {
  console.log(data)

  if (data.name) {
    let oldWidth = parseFloat(progressBar.style.width)
    progressBar.style.width = oldWidth + currentPercent + '%'
    resultField.innerHTML = resultField.innerHTML + '<br>' + data.name
  }
}

function request(url, method) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }),
  }).then(r => r.json()).catch(error => console.error(error))
}

function clear() {
  progressBar.style.width = '0%'
  resultField.innerHTML = ''
}
```

```css
.progressBarBox {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.progressBarBox>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h3>Progress Bar SW API</h3>
<label>
    Сколько будем загружать (не больше 80):
    <input type="number" value="15" id="count" max="80">
</label>
<button onclick="loadList(document.getElementById(`count`).value);">
Загрузить список элементов</button>

<div class="progressBarBox">
  <span id='progressBar' style="width: 0.5%"></span>
</div>

<div id="resultField"></div>
```

Comment: parseInt() до 100% прогресс-бар редко догоняет))

Comment: Поправил, стало получше)